# I woulk like to hide/unhide 2 columns in excel and toggle with same button

Tags: excel

I woulk like to hide/unhide 2 columns in excel and toggle with same button . I need a Macro script to do that. I do not have  a vba script to to that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner:

```
Sub klkj()
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Hidden = Not ActiveSheet.Columns("A:B").Hidden
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Scott. That worked. Really helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi SCott, just 1 more addition to above script. By default i want the column to be hidden. Can you help me add that step please?